# How to get the raw JSON coming from an IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm using Streaming Analytics to retrieve JSON messages being placed on an IoTHub. I need to be able to retrieve, and store, in a SQL Server table, the raw JSON string. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you wrap the json as string in another json object that is send to the IoT Hub.

Otherwise the solution would be to try whether you can stringify / construct the json object using a [Javascript function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) and then store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

- **Retrieve**

Streaming Analytics Job **does** support retrieve **JSON** messages from IoT Hub. You can set the event serialization format to JSON type when adding stream input like this:

[image]

- **Store**

Streaming Analytics Job support write to SQL Database.

But **note**:

> Currently the Azure SQL Database offering is supported for a job
>   output in Stream Analytics. However, an Azure Virtual Machine running
>   SQL Server with a database attached is not supported. This is subject
>   to change in future releases.

So if you mean "SQL Server table" as Azure Virtual Machine running SQL Server with a database, the answer is "NO" currently.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I asked how I can retrieve the raw JSON string that was sent to the hub. I didn't ask if Stream Analytics can process JSON.